# How to update specific rows using laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table:

```
ID|user_id|group_id|subject |book_id|duplicate
 1| 2     |3       |history |1      |         
 2| 4     |3       |history |1      |
 3| 5     |3       |history |1      |
```

I want the resulting table to look like this:

```
ID|user_id|group_id|subject |book_id|duplicate
 1| 2     |3       |history |1      |         
 2| 4     |3       |history |1      |1
 3| 5     |3       |history |1      |1
```

I want all ascending IDs after the lowest `ID` duplicate column to be updated to 1. PLEASE NOTE: the IDs are dynamic and so simply using `->where(ID, '>', 1);` will not work in all cases.

so far I have this

```
$duplicates = DB::table('table')
               ->where('subject', 'history')
               ->where('book_id', 1)
             ->skip(1)->take(1)
            ->update(['duplicate' => 1]);
```

The code above does not work because I get a resulting table that looks like this:

```
ID|user_id|group_id|subject |book_id|duplicate
 1| 2     |3       |history |1      | 1        
 2| 4     |3       |history |1      |
 3| 5     |3       |history |1      |
```

Comment: Have you even bothered to read the Laravel documentation? http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#basic-updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
DB::table('table')
->where('subject', 'history')
->where('book_id', 1)
->where('id', '>', 1)
->update(['duplicate' => 1]);
```

Comment: your answer is correct however I've edited the question. Sorry I forgot to mention that ID is dynamic.

Comment: Then replace `1` with the variable that stores the dynamic value. i.e: `->where('id', '>', $dynamicId)`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply an offset to an `UPDATE` query, which is not a valid SQL (I am assuming that the query builder silently ignores your `skip(1)->take(1)` call when `update()` is called.)

One way to achieve the result you're looking for is to find all ids that should be marked as non-duplicate (duplicate = null) and then update every other relevant record.

**Concrete book**

```php
$original = DB::table('table')
    ->select('id')
    ->where('subject', 'history')->where('book_id', 1)
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')->first()->pluck('id'); // Lowest id

DB::table('table')
    ->where('subject', 'history')->where('book_id', 1)
    ->whereNot('id', $original) // All, but one
    ->update(['duplicate' => 1]);
```

**All Books**

```php
$originals = DB::table('table')
    // One for every combination of `subject` and `book_id`
    ->groupBy('subject', 'book_id')>orderBy('id', 'asc') 
    ->lists('id');

DB::table('table')
    ->whereNotIn('id', $originals) // All, but one for every book
    ->update(['duplicate' => 1]);
```

You can further optimise either example to employ a sub-query instead two separate queries.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to update every relevant record that does not match non-duplicates. I want to update all but one.

Comment: @Billy, I wrote the initial answer in a hurry which resulted in code that didn't do what I intended it to do. I've updated it now with clearer phrasing as well as correct code.